# Weak topology : defined by linear mapping vs semi-norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Wikipédia:

-The weak topology on X is the initial topology with respect to X* (let's note it T') -If the field K has an absolute value , then the weak topology σ(X,F) is induced by the family of seminorms,|f| where f is a linear continuous form (let's note it S)

How to see that the two topology are the same ? If we consider T', we deduce that |f|is also continuous from (X,T') to R (by composition) so S (wich is the smallest topology who make the |f| continuous) S⊂T ′
But conservely i don't see....

Comment: Are you familiar with initial topologies?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: If $f$ is a linear functional so that $|f|$ is continuous (in whatever vector space topology), then $f$ itself is continuous, because
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x-y)|.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help: "(in whatever vector space topology)" ok so you suppose that the initial topology induced by |f| get the structure of a vector space topology, this is not so trivial!

Comment: But $|f|$ is a seminorm, and it is a standard result that a family of seminorms induces a vector space topology.

Comment: Thank you so i will try to prove that first :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if we assume that topology induced by semi-norm has a vectorial topology structure i feel stupid. The solution should be that : we want to prove that $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ we can show that: $\forall \varepsilon >0,\exists V \in \mathcal{V}(x_0)$ such that $\forall y \in V :|f(y)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon $. As we know that $X$ is equiped with vector space topology we know that translation are continuous so $|f(y)-f(x_0)|=|f(y-x_0)|=|f| \circ \tau_{-x_0}(y)$ with $|f| \circ \tau_{-x_0}$ continuous on whole $X$ (by composition). Now we use the fact that

- $|f| \circ \tau_{-x_0}$  is coninuous in particular in $x_0$.
- $|f| \circ \tau_{-x_0}(x_0)=0$ (cause f is linear)

  So $\forall \varepsilon >0,\exists V \in \mathcal{V}(x_0)$ such that $\forall y \in V :||f| \circ \tau_{-x_0}(y)-|f| \circ \tau_{-x_0}(x_0)|=|f(y-x_0)-0|=|f(y)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon $

Thanks Harald :)
Ps: does anyone can send me a link wich prove that topology indued by semi-norms has a vectorial topology structure?